# Usage of StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, json, streamreader, portable-class-library

I want to read a file data.json and convert it to a string.

My code is this one:

```
String json = null;

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("data.json"))
{
     json = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

but Visual Studio tells me that `StreamReader` does not expect a String as constructor argument.

How can I tell StreamReader that I want to read the file data.json?

Comment: basically it says that new StreamReader("data.json") is wrong

Comment: What kind of app are you writing? Is this for a Windows Phone app, for example?

Comment: @PatrickHofman: It depends on the framework you're using. That's not in the PCL, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `StreamReader` supports [constructor which accepts file path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) for most platforms, but not all. But anyway - simply use [`File.ReadAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("data.json");
```

It creates `StreamReader` internally ([link to source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs)):

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding))
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

UPDATE: You can always pass stream to `StreamReader`. Use `FileStream` to open stream for reading file, and then pass it to `StreamReader`:

```
string json = null;
using (var stream = new FileStream("data.json", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: See the second constructor (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.StreamReader(v=vs.110).aspx). It isn't supported on PCL.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Portable Class Libraries and it looks like I dont have System.IO.File. So I cant do File.ReadAllText("data.json");

Comment: @NicolaSecco please add appropriate tags to your questions

Comment: But I am in the shared project, not in Android, so how can I use Assets.Open?

Comment: @NicolaSecco OK, I see now. Just use `FileStream` - see updated sample. Also you can write your own `File` class which does the same behind the scene

Comment: Apparently FileStream and FileMode don't exist in PCL

Comment: @NicolaSecco looks like your only option is usage of [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) package